# Any idea how to Convert this to Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
DB::select("select encoded_datas.* from encoded_datas inner join
            (select data_user_firstname, data_user_lastname, data_user_barangay from encoded_datas t
            group by data_user_firstname, data_user_lastname, data_user_barangay
            having count(*)>1) t1
          on encoded_datas.data_user_firstname=t1.data_user_firstname and encoded_datas.data_user_lastname=t1.data_user_lastname and encoded_datas.data_user_barangay=t1.data_user_barangay");
```

It's a working piece of query code, but it is so slow to load compare to Eloquent/Proper Query Builder.

Can anyone here help me convert this to Laravel's Query Builder format..

Comment: Changing from DB::select to Eloquent won't speed up the query. Carefully examining your query and adjusting it (or adding indexes) using things like `EXPLAIN` will be important.

Comment: Are you trying to get duplicates?

Comment: Hi @Alexandr, yes im getting duplicate datas and show it in datatables.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

```
DB::connection(your_connection)
->table('encoded_datas')
->select('encoded_datas.*')
->join(
    DB::raw("SELECT data_user_firstname, data_user_lastname, data_user_barangay FROM encoded_datas t GROUP BY data_user_firstname, data_user_lastname, data_user_barangay HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t1"),
    function($join {
        $join->on('encoded_datas.data_user_firstname', '=', 't1.data_user_firstname')
             ->on('encoded_datas.data_user_lastname', '=', 't1.data_user_lastname')
             ->on('encoded_datas.data_user_barangay', '=', 't1.data_user_barangay');
    })
)
```

but I don't think it will speed up execution

Comment: Thank you Alex, will try this one out.
What I meant by speed up is the loading of data in Datatables..
I already compared the two, eloquent query loads data in database in 2 - 3 seconds.. and the code above loads roughly 30 - 40 seconds.

Comment: to optimize the loading times in the datatables you can use the server side mode. Here is the link to the documentation : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: Hi @Alex, i've tried Alexandr's code and its working, But it doesn't show the other duplicate data.. The code that im using before shows duplicate datas in the table.. Like if there's 2 duplicate data, it will also show that 2 data in the table.. But using Alexandr's code, it only shows single data.

Comment: @GSIxz add more groupBy values. I'v given example with grouping only firstname, lastname. Try grouping the same like in your example `data_user_firstname, data_user_lastname, data_user_barangay`.
You wont be able to see 2 rows with the same firstname, lastname, since thats exactly what grouping does. It merges duplicate rows. But if you groupby firstname, lastname and barangay, you might see 2 rows with the same firstname, lastname IF the barangay are differrent

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes sending multiple requests might be less expensive then sending one nested.

You can try getting the ids of the duplicate rows first

```
$ids = DB::table('datas')
->select('firstname','lastname', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('firstname', 'lastname')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
->pluck('id');
```

Then get datas

```
$datas = Datas::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

In your example you are executing two queries and a join.

Here we are executing 2 queries only, 1 of which uses primary key index, which should be instant. Technically its should be faster, looks cleaner as well

Comment: i've updated my post with some example.

Comment: Hi @Alexandr, i've tried your code and its working, But it doesn't show the other duplicate data.. The code that im using before shows duplicate datas in the table.. Like if there's 2 duplicate data, it will also show that 2 data in the table.. But now using your code, it only shows single data.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Alexandr's code:

```
$ids = DB::table('datas')
->select('firstname','lastname', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('firstname', 'lastname')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
->pluck('id');
    
    
$datas = Datas::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

But it only shows single data/record.. What i want to get is something like this:

```
**id** |firstname    |lastname    

1      | John        | Legend

2      | john        | Legend

3      | Michael     | Mooray

4      | Smith       | West 

5      | smith       | West
```

so Im expecting to get the following result:

```
john  |Legend
john  |Legend
Smith |West
Smith |West
```